# Having a keyboard key that has multiple purposes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keyboard-events

I want to make a key combination with Keys <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> hence when both keys are pressed, purpose X starts. But my Key <kbd>D</kbd> is also being used to start purpose Y. How do I make sure when I'm pressing the key <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, purpose X and only Purpose X is started and not Purpose Y.

FYI --- Shift will be pressed before D.

I tried solving this problem myself, here is my code...

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == moveRight && isJumping != true && isHovering != true)
    {
        if (Shft_KeyPressed == true)// This block was suppose to fix my problem
        {
            canFly = true; // method for Purpose X will then start if this is true

        } else
        {
            facingDirection = 1;
            standTimer.Stop();
            Walking_Animator(); // This is Purpose Y        
        }            

    } else if (e.Shift)
    {
        Shft_KeyPressed = true;
        Flying_Animator(); // this is Purpose X
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well since D is always going to be true in both scenarios, you need to be explicit in your checks. If you don't want one to trigger when shift is held, then you need to also check that shift is not held. I also do not believe shift triggers keydown, but in any case your check should be `e.KeyCode == moveRight && e.Shift` or `e.KeyCode == moveRight && !e.Shift`.

Comment: Why the downvote, whats wrong with my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if <kbd>D</kbd> is pressed or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is pressed you can rely on [`KeyData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keydata(v=vs.110).aspx) property of event argument.

> [**KeyData**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keydata(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   A Keys representing the key code for the key that was pressed,
>   combined with modifier flags that indicate which combination of CTRL,
>   SHIFT, and ALT keys was pressed at the same time.

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.D)
{
    // Just D is pressed
}
if (e.KeyData == (Keys.D | Keys.Shift))
{
    // Exactly Shift + D is pressed
}
```

**Note 1:** You can also use `Shift` property to check if <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed. But keep in mind if `Shift` is true, it doesn't mean <kbd>Shift</kbd> is the only pressed modifiers key. But above criteria which I checked guarantees that the pressed combination is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

**Note 2:** If you are using `KeyDown` event, to receive the keys even when other controls of the form contain focus, you should set `KeyPreview` to `true`. Also as another option you can override `ProcessCmdKey` without setting `KeyPreview`. You have access to key data combination in `ProcessCmdKey` as well.

Comment: the | operator, what is it called, just curious, never seen it before

Comment: It's [Bitwise OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/or-operator) and used because [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration is decorated with `[Flags]` attribute.